# install rename command in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, batch-rename

In linux exist the `rename` command, for rename a set of files with regular expresions.

```
rename 's/prefix_//' *.jpg
```

if I search in the cygwin package I find the `renameutils` package, but this don't install the the rename command, Install qmv and other similars.

How I can install `rename` in cygwin ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rename` is provided by the `util-linux` package which can be found under the following categories in the Cygwin installer.

- System
- Text
- Utils

If you would like to find out which package provides a particular executable, you can use the [`cygcheck` command](http://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html) which comes with Cygwin by default.

```
$ cygcheck -p 'rename\.exe'
Found 6 matches for rename\.exe
x86_64/gvfs/gvfs-1.16.3-1
x86_64/gvfs/gvfs-1.16.4-1
x86_64/gvfs-debuginfo/gvfs-debuginfo-1.16.3-1
x86_64/gvfs-debuginfo/gvfs-debuginfo-1.16.4-1
x86_64/util-linux/util-linux-2.21.2-1
x86_64/util-linux-debuginfo/util-linux-debuginfo-2.21.2-1
```

Comment: Definitely helpful, but this doesn't explain how to install or use `rename` in the environment.

Comment: @jsleuth, How to install it is in the first sentence of my answer. You have to use the cygwin installer and select the `util-linux` package. The original question provides example usage and does not ask how to use it once it is installed. One would have to assume the OP already knows how to use the command.

Comment: I believe it is clear that the OP is looking for the Perl-based `rename`, the one allowing the use of regular expressions. At least, I am. The `rename` from `util-linux` does not accept Perl-like substitutions.

Answer (score 6):

The program with regular expression functionality that you require is a Perl script, sometimes called Perl Rename, or `prename`. It is usually distributed with Perl and is a different program to the `rename` provided by `util-linux`.

One way to enable it on Cygwin is to download it from [GitHub](https://github.com/subogero/rename). This just requires that you have the Perl Cygwin package installed.

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/subogero/rename/master/rename
mv rename ~/bin
chmod +x ~/bin/rename
PATH=~/bin:$PATH    # Add this to your ~/.bashrc to make it permanent
which rename
```

Comment: I had to use this method since installing it in Cygwin with `apt-cyg` or `sage` says it worked fine, but I still only have the original utility available.

Comment: This was the only method That worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

By default, *cygwin* does not come with rename ability.  The package `util-linux` is required.

Cygwin’s *rename* command renames files if you tell it the exact name of your target file.  This is the same as the **`mv`** command.

Syntax:

```
mv <filename> <new filename>
```

Comment: It seems that `util-linux` provides the more standard `rename` command. The one allowing the use of regular expressions is instead the Perl-based alternative. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/275278/265461) for a slightly more datailed distinction.

Answer (score 0):

download from http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/util-linux-ng.htm

extract and overwrite

C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64

[image: like this]

Comment: Unfortunately, does not work for me: the binary does not do anything. should I be worried that these files are from 2008?